# Detect Orientation of iPad - Swift Playgrounds

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have the following code running in Swift Playgrounds, but each time I change the orientation of the iPad, the code prints "Unable to Determine State". Am I doing something wrong or is there another way?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .portrait:
            print("Portrait")
        case .landscapeLeft:
            print("Landscape Left")
        case .landscapeRight:
            print("Landscape Right")
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            print("Portrait Upside Down")
        default:
            print("Unable to Determine State")
        }
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MainViewController()
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Ran into the same thing too...

Answer (score 0):

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft{

}
else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight{

}
else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown{

}
else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.UIDeviceOrientationPortrait{

}
```

for Swift 4:

```
 override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    var text=""
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation{
    case .Portrait:
        text="Portrait"
    case .PortraitUpsideDown:
        text="PortraitUpsideDown"
    case .LandscapeLeft:
        text="LandscapeLeft"
    case .LandscapeRight:
        text="LandscapeRight"
    default:
        text="Another"
    }
    print("You have moved: \(text)")        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still didn't work. Also, the code isn't updated for Swift 4.